# Three.js Envmap how to turn off

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have an environment map in my scene

```
sceneTarget.environment = envMap;
sceneTarget.background = envMap;
```

so my question is : **how to turn off the environment ?**

also I don't want to condition my RGBELoader() with a `if(loadAnEnvMap){// ... ...}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To disable an assigned environment map, you can do one of two things:

A. Assign `scene.environment = null`

B. For each material, assign `material.envMapIntensity = 0`

---

three.js r151